# Separate Id and name in key of JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, key-value

I have data on worker in my database in JSON format. which looks like this

```
{"45051-Cortador 1 Siloc": "hsgvs", "45063-Nihil impedit quia": "okbbd",}
```

in this JSON Key contains id and name of user for example in first key **45051**  is id and **Cortador 1 Siloc** is name of user.
I want id from key so that I can use it and I want to use it in Laravel Controller(PHP).
Thanks,

Comment: .are you looking for php or javascript sollution ?if javascript then update question to javascript solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use split here

```js
const obj = {
  "45051-Cortador 1 Siloc": "hsgvs",
  "45063-Nihil impedit quia": "okbbd",
};

const result = Object.keys(obj).map((s) => s.split("-"));

console.log(result);

result.forEach(([k, v]) => console.log(k, v));
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. can I achieve this in Laravel controller(PHP)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use collection

```
 $result= collect(json_decode($json))->map(function ($item,$key){

        $data=explode("-",$key);

        return ['id'=>$data[0]??null,'name'=>$data[1]??null];
    })->values()
```